# MS Access Query from form for multiple records in text box

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have created a form in Access which queries a single record in a set date range. This works beautifully. My question is how can I query multiple records from a form text box.

Something Similar to the SQL function

IN ('XXX','XXX','XXX')

I want my users to be able enter multiple values on the form and it will spit out the corresponding Data.

Comment: You could break up the string based on a key character (; , : etc.) and then use a for loop to concatencate each inbetween item to the end of a query string.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Split() function.  Something like this:

```
Dim arr() As String
Dim MySQL as String

If Len(Me!MyTextbox) > 1 Then
MySQL = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyField in ("

arr = Split(Me!MyTextbox.Text, ",")
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    MySQL = MySQL & "'" & arr(i) & "', "
Next

MySQL = Left(MySQL, Len(MySQL) - 2) & ")"

Me.RecordSource = MySQL
Else
   MsgBox "There are no values to search for."
EndIf
```

You would just loop through the array and add each value to a WHERE string.  You would have to instruct your users (via a label on the form) to separate values using a comma.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to allow multiple entries it's generally better to have a datasheet subform where users can enter data one per row. Then you use the subform data in queries just like a regular table.